# Matlab big matrix

Tags: windows, matlab

I'm trying to use matlab for the first time but I'm having a problem because the matrix I'm using is too big, I think.. I command I'm trying is:

m=[1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;169201]7;531456;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017;1692017]

And I'm getting the following error: Error: Unexpected MATLAB expression.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I spy a syntax error : `;169201]7;` , see the close-bracket in there? ; ) Try correcting it and see what you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That matrix is tiny :-) Matlab can handle millions of elements per matrix.

However, on the second line, you have an extra bracket that ruins things:

...17;1692017;169201 **]** 7;5...

Get rid of it, and you'll be fine!

Answer (score -2):

Seems like you are trying to do a matrix, but typing its code wrongly. First, the ; separates lines; if you want to separaate columns in a row you have to use a space.

And you have two closing ], while you have only one opening [ which is clearly incorrect

Comment: space or comma for separating row elements